# How do i add a content-md5 header to HttpRequestMessage.Headers in C# when i'm uploading on S3 server?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, uwp, http-headers, httprequest

Both methods `Add(TKey, TValue)` and `TryAppendWithoutValidation(String, String)` of `HttpRequestHeaderCollection` class don't work.

if i use `HttpRequestMessage.ToString` i can see that the `authorization`header has `SignedHeaders=content-md5` inside, but content-md5 is not among the headers but in the field after.

This is what i get (i removed the values).

```
Headers:
{
  x-amz-date: 
  x-amz-meta-content-type: 
  x-amz-user-agent: 
  x-amz-content-sha256: 
  x-amz-security-token: 
  authorization: 
}{
  Content-Type: 
  Content-MD5: 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Content` of the `HttpRequestMessage` has a header collection (HttpContentHeaderCollection) too.

Set the MD5 value in the [HttpContentHeaderCollection.ContentMD5 property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.headers.httpcontentheadercollection.contentmd5#Windows_Web_Http_Headers_HttpContentHeaderCollection_ContentMD5). The link also provide a sample on calculating the MD5 value which is an `IBuffer` instead of plain text.

Comment: i tried but i get
'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.'
anyway.

Comment: this is the response returned from amazon s3, google the error find some hits for me. maybe it is caused by other problem...

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the `HttpContentHeaderCollection.ContentMD5` property unhelpfully converts its value to Base 64.